# Cygwin сборка со -static: не находит библиотеку

Tags: cygwin, компоновщик, компиляция

```
gcc *.c -O2 -W -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -lm -lpng16 -lz -o zopfli
```

Работает, но при использовании:

```
gcc *.c -static -O2 -W -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -lm -lpng16 -lz -o zopfli
```

линкер не может найти **-lpng16**. Также пробовал **-lpng**

Конечно же, libpng16-devel установлена.